# Is there a 64-bit version of Microsoft Common Controls (MSCOMCTL.OCX)?

Tags: winapi, 64-bit, activex

Did Microsoft port `MSCOMCTL.OCX` to 64-bit?

I don't have it installed and I can't find it for download or find anything saying that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is a VB6 control. VB6 isn't really supported on 64-bit Windows, in fact Microsoft dropped all support for it back in 2005 but it may still work.
Here's the download [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/vb60pro/install/6/win98me/en-us/vbrun60.exe). Some people have had some success getting it installed. It needs to go in the windows/syswow64 folder. Best of luck.

BTW, it is a 32-bit control so you won't be able to use it for an 64-bit application.

Update:

Oops, gave the wrong link. That was the vb6 runtime. Here's the common [controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=25437d98-51d0-41c1-bb14-64662f5f62fe). You'll have to extract and register them manually. Use any cab file extractor.

Answer (score -5):

OCX is COM bassed. But COM don't have 64-bit implementation.